# In R Shiny, how to reactively reset user inputs inside a modal dialogue box?

Tags: r, shiny, modal-dialog, shiny-reactivity

The below MWE code works as intended, except that I would like clicking the "Reset" action button within the modal dialogue box to cause the matrix input grid within the modal dialogue to instantly (reactively) reset to default values (object `matrix3Default`) and the rendered table within the main panel to also instantly (reactively) reset to default values (object `matrix3Default`).

As drafted, after clicking "Reset", the matrix input grid and rendered table in main panel only re-render after the user clicks on the "Modify..." action button in the sidebar panel.

How do I make the "Reset" button immediately reactive, when user clicks on "Reset"?

My unsuccessful attempt to do this is indicated below under "BELOW ATTEMPT..."

When running this, make changes/additions to the user input grid so you can see how it resets.

MWE code:

```
library(shiny);library(shinyMatrix);library(shinyjs)

colnames(matrix3Default) <- paste0("Series ",1:ncol(matrix3Default))

matrix3Default <- matrix(c(1,24,0,100),4,1,dimnames=list(matrix3Headers(), NULL))

matrix3Headers <- function(){c('A','B','C','D')}

matrix3Input <- function(x, matrix3Default){
  matrixInput(x,label='Input series terms into below grid:',value=matrix3Default, 
              rows= list(extend=FALSE,names=TRUE),cols= list(extend=TRUE,names=TRUE,
                    editableNames=FALSE,delete=TRUE),class='numeric')}

ui <- 
  pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel("Model..."),
    sidebarPanel(
      fluidRow(helpText(h5(strong("Base Input Panel")))), 
      uiOutput("Panels") 
    ), # close sidebar panel
    
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Liabilities module", value=4,
                 fluidRow(h5(strong(helpText("Select model output to view:")))),
                 fluidRow(actionButton('showLiabStructBtn','Liabilities')),
                 div(style = "margin-top: 5px"),
                 uiOutput('showResults')), 
        id = "tabselected"
      ) # close tabset panel
    ) # close main panel
  ) # close page with sidebar

server <- function(input,output,session)({
  
  showResults <- reactiveValues()
  rv          <- reactiveValues( 
    mat3      =  matrix3Input('matrix3',matrix3Default),
    input     =  matrix3Default,
    colHeader =  colnames(input))
  
  output$Panels <- renderUI({
    tagList( 
      conditionalPanel(
        condition="input.tabselected==4",
        actionButton('modLiabStruct','Modify Liabilities Structure'))
    ) # close tagList
  }) # close renderUI
  
  vectorLiabStruct <- reactive({
    if(!isTruthy(input$modLiabStruct)){ 
      df <- matrix3Default
      df
      n <- dim(df)[2]
      colnames(df) <- paste("Series", 1:n)
      rownames(df) <- matrix3Headers()
    }
    else{ 
      req(input$matrix3) 
      rv$mat3 <- matrix3Input('matrix3',input$matrix3) 
      df <- input$matrix3
      n <- dim(df)[2]
      colnames(df) <- paste("Series", 1:n)
      rownames(df) <- matrix3Headers()
      rv$input <- df
    } # close else
    df})
  
  output$table3 <- renderTable({
    if(!isTruthy(input$modLiabStruct)){ 
      df <- matrix3Default
      df
      n <- dim(df)[2]
      colnames(df) <- paste("Series", 1:n)
      rownames(df) <- matrix3Headers()
    }
    else{ 
      req(input$matrix3) 
      rv$mat3 <- matrix3Input('matrix3',input$matrix3) 
      df <- input$matrix3
      n <- dim(df)[2]
      colnames(df) <- paste("Series", 1:n)
      rownames(df) <- matrix3Headers()
      rv$input <- df
    } # close else
    df},rownames=TRUE, colnames=TRUE)
  
  observeEvent(input$modLiabStruct,{ 
    showModal(modalDialog( 
      rv$mat3,
      footer = tagList(
        actionButton("resetLiabStruct","Reset"), 
        modalButton("Close")
      ), # close tag list
    )) # close show modal and modal dialog
  }) # close observe event
  
  observeEvent(input$showLiabStructBtn,{showResults$showme<-tagList(tableOutput("table3"))},ignoreNULL=FALSE)  
  
  # BELOW ATTEMPT...
  observeEvent(input$resetLiabStruct,{
    rv$input <- matrix3Default
    rv$mat3  <- matrix3Input('matrix3',matrix3Default)
    {showResults$showme <- tagList(tableOutput("table3"))}
  },ignoreNULL = TRUE) # close observe event

  output$showResults <- renderUI({showResults$showme})
}) # close server

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get this behavior because once loaded by your first `observeEvent()` (`input$modLiabStruct`), the `matrix3` shown in the modal box doesn't refresh itself.

Since it is a `matrixInput`, you need to update it with an updateInput-type function, thankfully it's [provided by the shinyMatrix package](https://rdrr.io/cran/shinyMatrix/man/updateMatrixInput.html). You can modify your `observeEvent` as follows:

```
observeEvent(input$resetLiabStruct, {
    updateMatrixInput(session, 'matrix3', matrix3Default)
  })
```